# How does Redux's compose() combine multiple store enhancers like Applymiddleware

Tags: reactjs, redux, functional-programming

I'm reading redux source code to understand how mutiple store enhancers get combined,
below is some code snippet:

```
export default function createStore(reducer, preloadedState, enhancer) {
  if (typeof preloadedState === 'function' && typeof enhancer === 'undefined') {
    enhancer = preloadedState
    preloadedState = undefined
  }

  if (typeof enhancer !== 'undefined') {
    if (typeof enhancer !== 'function') {
      throw new Error('Expected the enhancer to be a function.')
    }

    return enhancer(createStore)(reducer, preloadedState)   // <------
  }

  // ...

  const store = {
    dispatch: dispatch,
    subscribe,
    getState,
    replaceReducer,
    // ...
  }

  return store
}
```

```
export default function applyMiddleware(...middlewares) {   
  return createStore => (...args) => {
    const store = createStore(...args)
    let dispatch

    const middlewareAPI = {
      getState: store.getState,
      dispatch: (...args) => dispatch(...args)
    }
    const chain = middlewares.map(middleware => middleware(middlewareAPI))
    dispatch = compose(...chain)(store.dispatch)

    return {
      ...store,
      dispatch
    }
  }
}
```

I use two store enhancers as:

```
// index.js
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";

export default createStore(rootReducer, compose(applyMiddleware(multiActions), asyncEnhancer(2000)));
```

and two store enhancers are:

```
export const multiActions = ({ dispatch, getState }) => next => action => {
   if (Array.isArray(action)) {
      action.forEach(a => next(a));
   } else {
      next(action);
   }
}

export const asyncEnhancer = delay => createStoreFunction => (...args) => {
   const store = createStoreFunction(...args);
   return {
      ...store,
      dispatchAsync:   
        (action) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         setTimeout(() => {
            store.dispatch(action);
            resolve();
         }, delay);
      })
   };
}
```

here is what I don't understand about the `compose` function https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/compose.ts:

```
export default function compose(...funcs: Function[]) {
  // ...
  return funcs.reduce(
    (a, b) =>
      (...args: any) =>
        a(b(...args))
  )
}
```

so `a` is `applyMiddleware(multiActions)` and `b` is `asyncEnhancer(2000)`, `args` is `createStore`, since `asyncEnhancer(2000)(createStore)` return an object `{ ...store, dispatchAsync: ...}`, how can this object be passed as an argument for `applyMiddleware(multiActions)` where it also need to be passed with `createStore`?